# Why do I get "error: variable 'sum_r' set but not used [-Werror,-Wunused-but-set-variable]" when I set a variable inside a for loop?

Tags: c, cs50

Why do I get an error, `error: variable 'sum_r' set but not used [-Werror,-Wunused-but-set-variable]` when I set the variables `sum_r` `sum_g`, and `sum_b` in a for loop then try to change their values later in another for loop?

Here is my current code:

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE new[height][width];

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int sum_r = 0;
            int sum_g = 0;
            int sum_b = 0;

            for (int ji = i - 1; ji < 3; ji++)
            {
                for (int jj = j - 1; jj < 3; jj++)
                {
                    int rgb_r = image[ji][jj].rgbtRed;
                    int rgb_g = image[ji][jj].rgbtGreen;
                    int rgb_b = image[ji][jj].rgbtBlue;

                    sum_r += rgb_r;
                    sum_g += rgb_g;
                    sum_b += rgb_b;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

I have tried using pointers and addresses but I cannot seem to figure it out. Could someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Looks like this only happens with clang 13 and later, and not with gcc.

Comment: There are multiple problems with the code. Not just summing some values and discarding them, but the iteration range of the inner loops, indexing out of range for edge pixels, and not copying the new image back to the original at the end.

Comment: This code isn;t complete yet, I ran into this issue and thought to ask about it here.

Comment: And it looks like changing `sum_r += rgb_r;` to `sum_r = sum_r + rgb_r;` makes the error go away.

Comment: That's very interesting, I guess I was worried because it said error and not warning.

Comment: Note that `ji < 3;` should be `ji <= i + 1;` similar for `jj`. A mistake, rather than incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You do not need `return` in a `void` function
2. You are getting this message because you set those variables in the loop but you do not use it. Your function can be reduced to the no-op and the compiler is warning that you forgot to do something with your value.

optimizing compilers will reduce this function to:

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cEeejGKrh

Comment: But the variables are being updated in the 4th loop, no?

Comment: @naber - But what good is a variable that you just write to, and never read from?